# Why are loops in matlab slower than in Python?

Tags: python, performance, matlab, loops

There is a number of posts in the internet, which state that Matlab executes loops so slowly, because it is an interpreted language. But as far as I know Python is interpreted as well.

Why is Python much faster than Matlab if it executes loops?

Comment: Programming languages don't have speeds, implementations do.

Comment: The latest releases of MATLAB have pretty good JIT acceleration, so loops are no longer "horrendously slow" in most cases. As for the comparison between MATLAB and Python, it's very vague unless you're comparing two specific implementations of the same thing.

Comment: @A.Rodas In this case, Matlab has one implementation (save for versions) and Python only has one common implementation, namely CPython, the officially distributed implementation by the Python Foundation.

Comment: @rubenvb CPython isn't the only used version of Python, it's the main one, but others are prevalent (PyPy, Jython, IronPython, etc...).

Comment: languages per se are neither interpreted nor compiled. You can actually do both on any language more or less (altough I'd hate to write a C interpreter...). The "interpreted languages", like perl, php, python are normally compiled (for that speed reason) and then executed (with python, they are normally even saved in a compiled version, that's what the *.pyc files are)

Comment: Do you have sources of direct comparisons between MATLAB and Python? Otherwise, your question is illegitimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: probably Matlab and Python achieve similar speeds in loops.

The sources that you found are likely comparing old versions of Matlab, as @Eitan mentioned the new versions have proper Just In Time mechanisms which speed simple loops up a lot.

There will be loops that python does faster, and those that Matlab does faster, but loop speed is probably not a relevant consideration when deciding between these two languages.